# Sorting array with Integer and then by decimal section of value in specific order using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have an array:

```
let arr = ['100.12', '100.8', '100.11', '100.9'];
```

after sorting getting output:

> '100.11', '100.12', '100.8', '100.9'

But I want it to be sorted like page indexing:

> '100.8', '100.9', '100.11', '100.12',

---

EDIT:
I have a few good solutions, but they are lacking in one place, for example:

```
arr1 = ['100.12', '77.8', '88', '77.11', '77.12', '77.9', '77', '119', '120', '100.8', '100.11', '100', '100.9']
```

result would be like:

> ["77.8", "77.9", "77.11", "77.12", "77", "88", "100.8", "100.11", "100.12", "100", "100.9", "119", "120"]

What is expected is:

> [ "77", "77.8", "77.9", "77.11", "77.12", "88", "100", "100.8", "100.11", "100.12", "100.9", "119", "120"]

Comment: I have tried sorting like:
`arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return Number(a ) - Number(b);
        });`

Comment: ex: arr1 = ['100.12', '77.8', '88', '77.11', '77.12', '77.9', '77', '119', '120', '100.8', '100.11', '100', '100.9'] result would be like: ["77.8", "77.9", "77.11", "77.12", "77", "88", "100.8", "100.11", "100.12", "100", "100.9", "119", "120"] here expected is : [ "77", "77.8", "77.9", "77.11", "77.12", "88", "100", "100.8", "100.11", "100.12", "100.9", "119", "120"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `string#localeCompare` with `numeric` property to sort your array based on the numeric value.

```js
let arr = ['100.12', '77.8', '88', '77.11', '77.12', '77.9', '77', '119', '120', '100.8', '100.11', '100', '100.9'];
arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true}))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This is awsm, Thanks a lot

Comment: this does not work with more decimal values. like this let arr = ['100.123456', '77.843566', '88.34578345', '77.112345', '77.125467', '77.92345', '77345.456', '119.1234', '120.345567', '100.89876', '100.11877354', '100.03245', '100.9'];

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple oneliner. You wanna sort by the integer part first, then if that is equal, by the decimal part.

```js
const arr =  ['100.12', '77.8', '88', '77.11', '77.12', '77.9', '77', '119', '120', '100.8', '100.11', '100', '100.9'];
const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
      if (parseInt(a) !== parseInt(b)) {
        return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
      }
      return (parseInt(a.split('.')[1], 10) || 0) - (parseInt(b.split('.')[1], 10) || 0);
    });
    
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Look at the outcome OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks  @NirTzezana, fixed.

Comment: this is almost there but it will cause issue in their is a whole number in this array ex: arr1 = ['100.12', '77.8', '88', '77.11', '77.12', '77.9', '77', '119', '120', '100.8', '100.11', '100', '100.9'] result would be like: ["77.8", "77.9", "77.11", "77.12", "77", "88", "100.8", "100.11", "100.12", "100", "100.9", "119", "120"] here expected is : [ "77", "77.8", "77.9", "77.11", "77.12", "88", "100", "100.8", "100.11", "100.12", "100.9", "119", "120"]

Comment: @sumitsharma adjusted for it, just for completeness sake, even though you accepted the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To compare and sort numbers by digits and decimal sections, you can create a custom sort to firstly check the integers parts first if they are not equal then compare if not then compare then compare the decimal section of them:

```js
let arr = ['100.12', '100.8', '100.11', '100.9'];

function customSort(a, b) {
    const [aInt, aDec] = a.split('.').map(Number);
    const [bInt, bDec] = b.split('.').map(Number);

    // Compare the integer parts first
    if (aInt !== bInt) {
        return aInt - bInt;
    }

    // If the integer parts are equal, compare the decimal parts
    return aDec - bDec;
}

arr.sort(customSort);

console.log(arr);
```